# Locked me out of my administrator after activating "Force SSL" (Redirect Loop)

Tags: joomla-3.x

now this is awkward, I activated "Force SSL" on the entire site and getting a redirect loop. I can't login on my admin because of the loop. Is there a way to disable this function outside of the Admin and how ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Open your configuration.php file on root of your site.
 Find

> public $force_ssl = '2';
>   and set it 0